# How to get the first value from a list of key value pair and assign to a variable in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have an ask to synchronize the metadata of one of our server using curl command and send out an email id it failed.

1. Get the username and password from Password Vault.--Done
2. Execute the curl command with username and password, in user variable.--Done
3. Update the log file.--Done
4. Send email notification in case of failure.

Example curl command: curl --request POST --user "jsmith:mypassword" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{ "allServers": "true", "priority": "serverwithlocalchanges" }' "https://denodo-server.acme.com:9090/denodo-data-catalog/apirest/synchronize"

Output of this command is key value pair, and I need to get the first value ie “OK” corresponding to the key “result” and assign to a variable.
Example: {"result":"ok","data":{"responses": etc..

Is there a way to get that using bash?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please update the question to supply more of the result data AND the expected output.  We can see you have some JSON like results, but there isn't enough there to let someone help with filtering the data to the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example small extract of the returns json, you can use jq and so:

```
resp=$(curl --request POST --user "jsmith:mypassword" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{ "allServers": "true", "priority": "serverwithlocalchanges" }' "https://denodo-server.acme.com:9090/denodo-data-catalog/apirest/synchronize" | jq -r '.result')
```

Comment: Any alternative without using jq?